# jQuery text animation from right to left

Tags: jquery, animation, text

I try to achieve the same animation with jQuery animate for social sharing what this [site](https://www.celine.com/en) uses in footer when you click on Share.

I was trying to build the animation but the list on toggle does not behave as expected.

my markup

```
<div id="social-media">
<a href="#" class="social-shares"> SHARE</a>

<ul class="social-media-channels">
  <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Google+</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#social-media {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
#social-media a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#social-media a:hover {
  color: silver;
}
#social-media .social-shares {
  float: right;
}
#social-media ul.social-media-channels {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: none;
}
#social-media ul.social-media-channels li {
  display: inline;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.social-shares').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.social-media-channels').animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 350);
  })
})
```

[here](http://codepen.io/lgt/pen/vOJMQM) is my codepen

Comment: sorry he had the codepen first, but I gave you an upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a height to ul

```
ul.social-media-channels {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin-right:15px;
    display:none;
    height:20px;
    li{
      display:inline;
    }
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdyQRG

Answer (score 2):

Add height to following css :

```
#social-media ul.social-media-channels {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
}
```

[working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJrXbq)